# Should we consider the line passing through the origin is having equal intercepts?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

I am a grade 11 student and I had the following question on my math test.

$x^2 +y^2+4x-8y+2=0$

is a circle and we have to find out the equations of the tangents of the circle that cuts off equal intercepts of the same sign from the axes of coordinates.

Naturally, I started with the equation being $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{a}=1$ and found 2 equations. I then thought that I was assuming that the intercepts can never be 0 if I only used the formula.

So I then used the formula $y=mx$ to find two more equations and then kept the 4 equations as the answer. I didn't get any marks; so I gave back the copy for a recheck as I still , to some extent, believe that I was right.

Was I right about this? Or I should have kept the 1st two equations only??

Some people wanted to know the process of how I found the equation more descriptively. Here it is:

Given, $x^2 +y^2+4x-8y+2=0$ is a circle.
$\therefore$ centre, $C \equiv (-2,4)$, Radius, $R =\sqrt{18}$

Now, let the equation be $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{a}=1$  where $a \neq 0$

$\implies x+y-a=0 \cdots (1)$.

$\therefore $ perpendicular distance to (1) from the centre

$ = \frac{|-2+4-a|}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}} $ which should be equal to the radius if the line I tangent.

$\therefore \frac{|-2+4-a|}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}} = \sqrt{18}\cdots (2)$

Solving 2 we get, $a=8,-4$

Again let,

Equation be $y-mx=0$ if the intercept is 0

Perpendicular distance from centre = $\frac{|2m+4|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}=\sqrt{18}$[Radius] $\cdots (3)$

solving 3 we get, $m=1,-\frac{1}{7}$

Thus the required equations of tangent are:

$x+y-8=0$

$x+y+4=0$

$y=x$

$7y=x$

Comment: With nothing assumed about $m,$ your  $y=mx$ just goes through all nonvertical lines through the origin. How does that ensure the two intercepts are equal on the two axes?

Comment: Does zero have sign?

Comment: If the origin is outside the circle, there will of course be two tangents from the origin (as from any point outside the circle). If you assume that the tangent has gradient $-1$ you will not pick these up and your other method should do that. Whether they count as solutions depends on the conventions you are using. They key thing is to explain in your answer what you have done (and draw a diagram to illustrate ...).

Comment: I am deleting my earlier comment, as I had the circle misplaced.  I suspect the question was not written clearly enough:  it looks like the poser only wanted the lines of slope $ \ -1 \ $ and hadn't considered that tangent lines through the origin exist, as per **Mark Bennet**'s comment.  The poser will likely argue that "equal intercepts on the coordinate axes" meant _non-zero_ values, but it doesn't _say_ that.  If nothing else in the problem statement implied the interceopts should not be zero, you and others would gave the additional lines have a case (provided _your_ results are correct).

Comment: I find this very hard to follow. I agree that the equation of the line should be $x/a+y/a=1$ for some value of $a$ and that lines through the origin may be relevant as well. But that is a separate case; you don't combine those equations. You didn't show how to you worked with the condition that the line be tangent to the circle. To me, that is the main point.

Comment: $y=a-x$ ($a\neq 0$) and $y=kx$ ($k\neq 0$) both correspond to statement "cuts off equal intercepts of the same sign from the axes of coordinates". Then there is 4 lines corresponding to problem statement. Even if your definition of sign says that zero has no sign, two zeroes have the same sign --- none.

Comment: 1. @coffeemath The line through origin has 0 intercepts on both axes. So aren't they equal?

Comment: 2. @MehmetKırdar 0 is neutral, as far as I know, and any sign should work. So both intercepts being 0, it think the line works well with the question

Comment: 3.@MarkBennet I did explain my answer as much as I could, Here I shortened it but now I edited and tried to give most of my answer. Could you please check it for me. [ The edited part is still abridged as I did not include the solving of the equations].

Comment: 4.@boojum If the rechecked solution still is not correct, should I take the solution to my teacher?

Comment: 5. @TedShifrin I edited the post and tried to give my full solution. Would you look at that, please? I didn't combine the equations, just made separate cases.

Comment: 6@IvanKaznacheyeu so I was right?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in yet another  way
$(x+2)^2+(y-4)^2=18$
Transform $x+2\to X$ and $y-4\to Y$ then the equation of the circle becomes $X^2+Y^2=18$ , now condition for $Y=mX+c$ to be tangent is $c^2=r^2(m^2+1)$, where r = radius of the circle . Now they move cut equal intercept on $x$ and $y$ axes(Also $X$ and $Y$ axes), therefore $m=1$(Disregarding the case of $m=-1$ because of same sign condition), this gives 2 quadratics and hence the 4 equations in $X$ and$Y$ co-ordinates , now convert them back to normal coordinate and this gives you the answer ...

Answer (score 0):

We have the circle $x^2+y^2+4x-8y+2 = 0$. We can rewrite that as $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c = 0$, where $g=2$, $f=-4$, and $c=2$. This means the center of the circle is $\left(-g,-f\right) = \left(-2,4\right)$ and the radius $r$ is $\sqrt{g^2+f^2-c} = \sqrt{(-2)^2+(4)^2-2} = 3\sqrt2$.

Consider the equation of a line $y=mx+c$, which we can rewrite as $mx-y+c = 0$. Notice how the intercepts are $\left(0,c\right)$ and $\left(-\frac{c}{m},0\right)$. If we want to find the "equal intercepts of the same sign from the axes of coordinates," then it makes sense to let $m=1$ or $m=-1$.

(The wording in quotes is confusing, so from here I just decided to find all the tangent lines in general.)

The distance we are looking for, which is also the radius, is given by

$$\frac{\left|m\alpha-\beta+c\right|}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} = r \iff r^2 = \frac{(m\alpha-\beta+c)^2}{1+m^2}.$$

Since the center is $\left(-2,4\right)$, we can plug in $-2$ and $4$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively, to get

$$\frac{(m(-2)-(4)+c)^2}{1+m^2} = 18.$$

Now we have to choose our $m$. If $m=-1$, then we can solve for $c$ to get $c=-4$ or $c=8$. If $m=1$, then we can solve for $c$ to get $c=0$ or $c=12$. This means the tangent lines are

$$\eqalign{
y&=-x+8 \cr
y &= -x-4 \cr
y &= x+12 \cr
y &= x+0
}$$

and notice how if you graph them along with the circle, they are lines tangent to the circle.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Your equation $y=x+12$ doesn't work as the intercepts become of different signs (one plus another minus). And another equation through the origin exists.

Comment: @MehrabHossain I was just listing off some possible tangent lines because I don't understand what "intercepts become of different signs (one plus another minus)" means. Does that mean something like $(0,a)$ and $(0,-a)$, or $(a,0)$ and $(-a,0)$?

Comment: Same sign means both intercepts are either positive or both intercepts are negative[something like (a,0)(0,a) or (-a,0)(0,-a)] or (maybe) 0. Different signs mean one negative or one positive and vice versa.

Comment: @MehrabHossain I see. Then I think your edited solution works.